# show / hide toggle function with multiple buttons not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to javascript and just wrote my first script.  The point of the script is to toggle a div on the screen with a click of a button, while changing the text on the button from show to hide, depending on if the div is visible or not.

When I place the one button on the page everything works good.  However when I add a second button to the page, the first button still works, but the second one does not work.

How can I add multple buttons and get the script to work on them?  I need the buttons to generate the hide / show text and I need this to work in ie7 + with no jquery.

```
var show = "show";
var hide = "hide";
var selector = document.getElementById('toggleCost');
var optionA = document.createTextNode(show);
var optionB = document.createTextNode(hide);
var targetClassCost = document.querySelector('.cost');

// determines the text, inside the element 
function textChange () { 

    if (targetClassCost.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        selector.appendChild(optionB);

    } else {
        selector.appendChild(optionA);  
    }

}

// toggles the text of the button when clicked
function toggle() {  

if (targetClassCost.style.visibility === 'visible') {
    targetClassCost.style.visibility = 'hidden';

} else {
    targetClassCost.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

    if (selector.innerHTML === show) {
        selector.innerHTML = hide;

    } else {
        selector.innerHTML = show;
    }

}
// calls the function that changes the text inside the element and inserts taht text into the button
selector.onclick = function () {toggle()};
textChange();
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dodey/Lexruaou/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are setting your selector at the start `var selector = document.getElementById('toggleCost');` you need to abstract your functions to accept a variable selector

Comment: hmmm ok.  Can you point me in the right direction on where i can find out how to do that?  I did some searching, and from the looks of it, i need to create an object, but im still not sure if this is what you are suggesting I do.

Comment: looks like your jsfiddle isnt working any more, would you mind putting it back up and i will give you some pointers :)

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out!  Here is the new link.

http://jsfiddle.net/dodey/Lexruaou/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/Lexruaou/3/)**

So the difference here is you can abstract the function so that you can apply it to any button to allow it to toggle the visibility and have its text changed each time it is clicked by passing in an element.

The issue with this is going to be that with multiple buttons attempting to control the visibility of the same element, they wont then 'listen' for the visibility change and have the text change propagated out to them.

I notice that you have the `textChange()` function that is really only used to set the initial text value of the buttons, we can reduce our code by removing this function and setting at the html level the default button text in readiness for your first click.

If we want this to be as extensible as possible, lets look at creating a function that allows us to pass in both the clickable items and the item(s) to be effected by the click handler's toggle.

```
var show = "show";
var hide = "hide";

var toggledSelectorClass = 'cost'; // class of element(s) to be hidden/shown
var togglerSelectorClass = 'toggleCost'; // class of element(s) to be clicked

function attachToggleVisibilityHandler(togglerClass, toggledClass){
    // finds all elements with matching class
    // note that getElementsByClassName is not supported in IE8
    // http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname
    var togglers = document.getElementsByClassName(togglerClass);
    var toggled = document.getElementsByClassName(toggledClass);

    // assigns the click event handler to each button with matching class
    for(var x = 0; x < togglers.length; x++){
        togglers[x].onclick = function(){
            toggleCostVisibility(togglers, toggled);
        }
    }
}

// toggles the visibility of the element(s)
function toggleVisibility(togglers, toggled) {
    for(var x = 0; x < toggled.length; x++){
        if (toggled[x].style.visibility === 'visible') {
            toggled[x].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            toggled[x].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
    toggleTextOnMatchingClassNames(togglers);
}

// changes the text of all buttons with matching class
function toggleTextOnMatchingClassNames(togglers){
    for(var x = 0; x < togglers.length; x++){
        if (togglers[x].innerHTML === show) {
            togglers[x].innerHTML = hide;            
        } else {
            togglers[x].innerHTML = show;
        }
    }
}

attachToggleVisibilityHandler(togglerSelectorClass, toggledSelectorClass);
```

What this essentially does is allows you to have multiple `.cost` elements (the "toggled" element(s)) and multiple `.toggleCost` elements (the "toggler" element{s}) that all stay in sync with one another.

Comment: Awesome! Ill go over it tonight and try it out.  I notice that for () loop you used is pretty common in alot of scripts.  Does this loop through the dom to find all the selectors your trying to find?

Comment: it's not the `for()` loop traversing the DOM. the line `document.getElementsByClassName` is the DOM traverser. It then stores all found elements in the variable it has assigned to. Because classes can be assigned to multiple elements i needed to accommodate for the possibility that the `getElementsByClassName` function returned an array of elements, not just one. So we loop through the results

Comment: If we knew we only wanted to deal with a single element we would use an `id` not a `class` on the element and use `getElementById` (as you originally did), thus eliminating the need for a `for()` loop when performing operations on its returned result (as we know it would only be 1 element returned)

Comment: I went to the fiddle and the buttons are not toggline, I dropped the code into my ide and no errors popped up on the console.  Would you mind taking one last peek at this to see whats going on?

Also i notice [x] in the code.  Can you explain to me what this does?

Comment: @David sorry that was my typo's fault, working now.. `x` is a counter (the `for` loop increases its number each time it loops). i am using `x` to target the `x`th item in the array.. so the first time it loops it looks for [0], then [1], then [2] etc.